# STL Map with structure

Tags: c++, stl

I have this structure:

```
struct tuple{int node; float cost};
std::map<int,std::set<tuple>> graph;
```

I'd like to know how to change the comparison operator for the map container so that i do not insert a key with repeated value like the example:

Ex.:

```
insert(1, {2,3})
insert(1, {2,4}) // not allowed
insert(1, {4,3}) // allowed
```

The containers are used for implement a graph thus whenever a node is already in another node adjacency, it can no longer be inserted in that adjacency.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain at a higher level what you're trying to do with this data structure?

Comment: The key is "1" and you can't have it twice!

Comment: All three inserts seem to use the same key...

Comment: the comparator compares only keys (in your case - `int`s), not values, you can't use a comparator that considers values in determining the order

Comment: Probably you need to have an vector<std::set> as value so that you can hold multiple set for same key. But be sure you can't insert same key again.

Comment: The structure stores the neighbours, i.e, the node itself and the cost to get to him from the key (also represents a node).

Comment: I suggest changing your graph definition to `std::map<std::pair<int,int>, int>` where `pair` contains `source` and `target` nodes, and `mapped_value` contains `cost`. This way you will not have two edges using custom comparator `std::less`

Comment: in this way: std::map<std::pair<int,int>, int>, how will i keep all the adjacency of a node?

Comment: How is `set<tuple>` supposed to sort its elements? What is `{2,3}` supposed to initialize? A `tuple`? A `set<tuple>`?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this. The key of your `map` is `int`, there is no way to make it look at the `tuple` as well.

Maybe you could replace the map with a `std::set<std::pair<int, std::set<tuple>>, Cmp>` where `Cmp` is

```
struct Cmp
{
  using value_type = std::pair<int, std::set<tuple>>;
  bool operator()(const value_type& l, const value_type& r) const
  {
    if (l.first < r.first)
      return true;
    if (l.first > r.first)
      return false;
    return l.second < r.second;
  }
};
```

This works because a `std::set` can examine any part of its `value_type` to determine the ordering of elements, whereas a `std::map` can only examine its `key_type`

You need to check the definition of the comparison though, it's not clear how you expect to use `std::set<tuple>` when `tuple` is not LessThanComparable, and it's not clear what you expect `insert(1, {3,4})` to do, when `{3,4}` is not a valid initializer for `set<tuple>`.